# How to highlight/search without scrolling, in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, search, scrolling

Sometimes I need to carefully read websites containing mostly text that are fairly long, and only a portion is displayed on-screen at any time. The portion displayed on-screen has a lot of text, and I want to highlight all instances of a certain word that appear on-screen.  I want this highlighting to happen while leaving the displayed text displayed, i.e. without scrolling the page.

For this purpose I currently use Chrome's "find" ctrl-f feature.  The problem is that if the on-screen text happens to have zero instances of that word, the page is automatically scrolled to the first instance where that word appears.  This is annoying, because now I need to scroll back to the original location, which might be quite far and otherwise difficult to find.

Is there some solution to this problem?

Comment: Would the downvoter please explain why?

Answer (score 2):

I just found [Selection Highlighter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/selection-highlighter/nepmkgohgoagfgcoegjaggacodcpdibj?hl=en), which seems to be a pretty good extension for this. It requires you to select an existing occurrence of the text you want to highlight, so it doesn't quite work like `Ctrl-F`. Particularly useful for online code-reviews, but may or may not be what you're looking for.

Comment: @music2myear: Technically I'm not sure whether it answers the original question. Regardless, I think this answer will be useful for many if not most people who find this page. It would've been for me. I'll edit the answer to avoid confusion. I don't care about downvotes.

Comment: Though a cool thing, but I want to write the query on my own, because I may not always find the needed word on a page. I just don't like that the scroll jumps between here and there so I feel completely lost, especially on long pages (when they have like 50-100 screens in height: documentation etc).

Answer (score 1):

The search happens on every keystroke by default. To avoid triggering unwanted searches you can type the search term somewhere (for example, the URL box) then copy and paste it into the search box.

Answer (score 0):

You can try various chrome extensions like 
I am not sure If this can exactly solve your need, but mostly it will.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/eftwo-f2-advanced-find-on/ccaikggmppdolhcehimngikgiafmdcep?hl=en

Evernote Clearly extension can also help you in reading stuff.

Comment: I've tried the first linked extension and it does not appear to help with this problem.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried scroll lock? It is supposed to prevent scrolling.

Also, if the site is not copy protected you can copy and paste to wordpad, or even better notepad++. Those will "Find next" instead of finding the first instance

Comment: Doesn't work, sorry.

Comment: @utkumaden Have you tried this yourself? It doesn't help solve his problem in any way. The find still scrolls down.

Comment: @VadimPonomarenko I updated the answer, it is not neat, but might do the trick.

Comment: @utkumaden, this is not a solution but a workaround.  Furthermore, this just moves the problem to making wordpad/notepad find without scrolling.

Comment: @VadimPonomarenko I know it is a workaround. I tried this, on notedpad ++, as long as the cursors is on the page you are reading, npp will find the first one **after** the cursor

Comment: But if the first one after the cursor is not currently visible, npp will scroll the page.  The problem is not fixed.

Comment: I guess I can't help you then, sorry